# Error en consulta de MySQL

Tags: mysql-workbench

Alguien puede ayudarme, como puedo hacer para que no me junte los campos de una consulta, es decir, hago la consulta y si es el mismo producto en vez de mostrarme las 2 filas me muestra 1 pero sumando las 2, se los muestro para que entiendan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la sentencia que estoy usando:

```
SELECT IL.Cliente, CA.Programa, IL.Estilo, IL.Color, SUM(IL.Total) AS Pares, CA.Material, CA.Departamento, CA.Fecha_Pago AS Fecha_Pedido 
FROM galaxyfx_produccion.compras_ange AS CA 
INNER JOIN galaxyfx_produccion.infolote AS IL ON CA.Programa = IL.Programa 
WHERE (CA.Programa LIKE '%40680%') AND (CA.Estado = 'En Espera') 
GROUP BY CA.Programa, CA.Material, CA.Departamento;
```

Ya intente de todo pero no queda.

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de el resultado esperado por tu consulta, ya que no entiendo muy bien que es lo que esperas obtener

Comment: Si te fijas en la imagen, se pueden ver las 2 primeras fila con el numero 1176, pues bien, se supone que ahi me tiene que mostrar 2 registros mas es decir, todos tienen que tener el numero 888, pero en la consulta me suma 2 registros, en ves de mostrarmelos separados

Comment: Select distinct  [...etc]

Comment: no funciona, ademas si hago eso, ya no me muestra la suma total de pares por programa

Answer (score 1):

Según entiendo, lo que necesitas es que no te sume el valor de tu columna Total, te está sumando el valor debido a que en la consulta tienes la instrucción `SUM()`. Para evitar que te haga la suma quita la instrucción. Tu consulta debería quedar mas o menos así:

```
SELECT IL.Cliente, CA.Programa, IL.Estilo, IL.Color, **IL.Total** AS 
Pares, CA.Material, CA.Departamento, CA.Fecha_Pago AS Fecha_Pedido 
FROM galaxyfx_produccion.compras_ange AS CA 
INNER JOIN galaxyfx_produccion.infolote AS IL ON CA.Programa = IL.Programa 
WHERE (CA.Programa LIKE '%40680%') AND (CA.Estado = 'En Espera') 
GROUP BY CA.Programa, CA.Material, CA.Departamento;
```

Tal vez tengas que agregar `IL.Total` al `Group By` como no conozco la estructura de tu base de datos no te lo podría decir con certeza.